# ASP.net core IdentityServer4 responds with invalid_grant when I try to refresh my access token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, postman, identityserver4

I have an ASP.net core IdentityServer4 project with following configuration:

**Startup.cs:**

```
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfiguration.IdentityResources())
                .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfiguration.TestUsers().ToList())
                .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfiguration.Clients())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryConfiguration.ApiResources());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseIdentityServer();
        }
    }
```

**InMemoryConfiguration.cs:**

```
 public class InMemoryConfiguration
    {
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new ApiResource("main", "main")
                {
                    UserClaims = new List<string>{ClaimTypes.Email}
                }, 
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources()
        {
            return new IdentityResource[]
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                new IdentityResources.Email(),
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mainclient",
                    ClientSecrets = new[] {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                    AllowedScopes = new[]
                    {
                        "main",
                        // IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        // IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess
                    },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
                },
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "apiclient",
                    ClientSecrets = new[] {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
                    AllowedScopes = new[] {"main",IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess},
                }
            };
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TestUser> TestUsers()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new TestUser
                {
                    SubjectId = "1",
                    Username = "jvanhoye@hotmail.com",
                    Password = "pass",
                    Claims = new List<Claim>{new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,"jvanhoye@hotmail.com55")}
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Then I use Postman to get an access token:
[Postman screen A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dDFn.png)

But when I try to refresh it using the refresh token from previous request I get 'Invalid_grant':
[Postman screen B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKijJ.png)

Anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to look into the log of identity server if there is some more info?

Answer (score 0):

When looked into the source code of IdentityServer4, there are a few integration tests that test `invalid_grant` return code.

In both of these cases this message is returned in case of

1. providing an invalid password
2. the user is locked out
3. the user is not allowed.

The validation is inside of class:

```
public class ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<TUser> : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
```

Some information can also be found in the log file of IdentityServer, it uses Serilog library, logging can be switched on in program.cs in `Main` method of the identityserver:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.File("logs\\some-file-name.txt")
    .CreateLogger();

BuildWebHost(args).Run();
```

Comment: How add custom error_description when error is locked out ?